# Set individual wedge hatching for pandas pie chart

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to make pie charts where some of the wedges have hatching and some of them don't, based on their content. The data consists of questions and yes/no/in progress answers, as shown below in the MWE.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

raw_data = {'Q1': ['IP', 'IP', 'Y/IP', 'Y', 'IP'],
        'Q2': ['Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'N/IP'],
        'Q3': ['N/A', 'IP', 'Y/IP', 'N', 'N']}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3'])
df= df.astype('string')

colors={'Y':'green', 
    'Y/IP':'greenyellow',
    'IP':'orange',
    'N/IP':'gold',
    'N':'red',
    'N/A':'grey'
    }
 
for i in df.columns:
    pie = df[i].value_counts().plot.pie(colors=[colors[v] for v in df[i].value_counts().keys()])
    fig = pie.get_figure()
    fig.savefig("D:/windows/"+i+"test.png")
    fig.clf()
```

However, instead of `greenyellow` and `gold` I am trying to make the wedges green with yellow hatching, and yellow with red hatching, like so (note the below image does not match the data from the MWE):

[image: Example of pie chart with hatching]

I had a look online and am aware I will likely have to split the pie(s) into individual wedges but can't seem to get that to work alongside the pandas value counts. Any help would be massively appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you absolutely need to use the pandas piechart? Can you use the piechart from matplotlib module?

Comment: @YuliaV It doesn't need to be a pandas piechart, that just seemed like the easiest way to create a plot like this that could be scaled up to data sets significantly larger than the one given (both in columns and rows). If there is a better way to do it I'm happy to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This snippet shows how to add hatching in custom colors to a pie chart. You can extract the Pandas valuecount - this will be a [Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) - then use it with the snippet I have provided.

I have added the hatch color parameter as a second parameter in the color dictionary:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

colors={'Y' :['green', 'lime'],
        'IP': ['orange', 'red'],
        'N' : ['red', 'cyan']}

labels=['Y', 'N', 'IP']

wedges, _ = plt.pie(x=[1, 2, 3], labels=labels)

for pie_wedge in wedges:
        pie_wedge.set_edgecolor(colors[pie_wedge.get_label()][1])
        pie_wedge.set_facecolor(colors[pie_wedge.get_label()][0])
        pie_wedge.set_hatch('/')

plt.legend(wedges, labels, loc="best")

plt.show()
```

The result looks like so:
[image]

Comment: Not working on latest `matplotlib>=3.5.1` as `plt.pie` return a tuple of 3 elements. Just change `wedges, _` by `wedges, *_` to make your snippet compatible with both oldest version and latest.

Comment: To get a visual result similar to the bicolor striped wedge in OP's question, you can add `plt.rcParams["hatch.linewidth"] = 5` to your code, which controls the width of the hatches (optimize value for your needs).